# While pasting text to UITextView, textViewDidChange: is not getting called

Tags: uitextview, pasting

I have a UITextView. I am resizing the text view based on the size of the text inside the method textViewDidChange. This works fine when I type. But this does not get calls when I paste something. Is it expected behavior or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Thats because pasting a text will not call textViewDidChange, but instead will call shouldChangeTextInRange.

What i do is detect if a text is being pasted, then call the methods i use to resize the textView. So in ur shouldChangeTextInRange delegate you will have similar to my answer in:

[how to know when text is pasted into UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454857/how-to-know-when-text-is-pasted-into-uitextview/34893463#34893463)