# How can I detect the use of autofill by the end user

Tags: ios, ios11, autofill

I would like to be able to detect when the user is currently using autofill feature (iOS 11), and then adapt some behavior in my UI. I didn't find any way to do that.

I tried the `Notification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive` way to detect that TouchID or FaceID is on going, but without success, the notification is sent too late to my view controller.

Any other ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect when user used Password AutoFill on a UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391814/how-to-detect-when-user-used-password-autofill-on-a-uitextfield)