# Is it possible to modify the AutoFill string before showing in textfield?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, autofill

I have to change the phone number string coming from AutoFill and then write to textfield. I used [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53465290/5130481) to detect AutoFill. But I have no access to string in that method. Is it possible?

Comment: That's what inside `replacementString`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
```

where `replacementString` is your answer

Comment: No, that is not the answer, as that string is not editable. If that string contains non-allowed characters you can't do anything before it gets pasted.