# Dismiss keyboard when Password Autofill suggestion is selected

Tags: ios, uitextfield, swift4, autofill

I have a loginViewController with Password Autofill feature. Everything works as it should except one small detail, which I cannot find a solution to. My conclusion is that there is none, but perhaps I could be wrong.

When the user selects a stored username and password, it autofills. But the keyboard stays open, and the user must dismiss the keyboard and press the log in button.

The documentation [Password autofill workflow](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/about_the_password_autofill_workflow) states that the delegate function:

```
  textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:
```

is called, when an quickbar item is pressed. I would like to close the keyboard so that the user can immediately press the log in button, and proceed, after a password is selected. But in this delegate function its not possible since its called whenever the textfields are modified as well.

Is there any solution to do this?

Comment: You would normally just handle the enter key on the keyboard as a login button rather than having the user dismiss the keyboard and have to tap a login button

Comment: Found this: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391814/how-to-detect-when-user-used-password-autofill-on-a-uitextfield)

Comment: @Paulw11 Fair enough, but link^ provided a solution for now.