# detect when the user paste some text in the textfield

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, swift5

when user sometimes copy some text from somewhere and paste on app's interface such as
textfeild of username and password for simplicity.How to detect that paste event.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to know when text is pasted into UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454857/how-to-know-when-text-is-pasted-into-uitextview)

Comment: I asked about the textfield,given answer was on UItextview.@YulianBaranetskyy

Comment: UITextField has a similar method `shouldChangeCharactersIn `, it is also mentioned on the link I posted, see: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/45960062/5049041](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45960062/5049041)

Comment: this will fail when the user is trying to paste one character,it is not passing all the conditions@YulianBaranetskyy

Comment: There's no bullet-proof way to detect that something was pasted. You need to use `shouldChangeCharactersIn` and you need to check against `UIPasteboard` - that's the principle. How picky it is though, is up to your code. You could also monitor `UIPasteboardChanged` to see if anything was copied into clipboard, and then compare it to the changes in `shouldChangeCharactersIn`.