# How to detect if a URL has been pasted/typed into a UITextView? Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextview

With Swift, how can I detect a user typing/pasting a URL into a UITextView?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to know when text is pasted into UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454857/how-to-know-when-text-is-pasted-into-uitextview)

Comment: @Scott, partly answers the question but only if someone was to paste a url. What if someone typed a url, how can we detect this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care if text is pasted or typed you can use this solution:

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {

    if (urlExists(textView.text))
    {
        // URL exists...
    }
}

func urlExists(_ input: String) -> Bool {
    let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
    let matches = detector.matches(in: input, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: input.utf16.count))

    for match in matches {
        guard let range = Range(match.range, in: input) else { continue }
        let url = input[range]
        print(url)
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

If you need to know that it pasted then use this.
If someone pastes it would be more than one character. We should avoid to use UIPasteboard because it could freeze in this scenarios and also show uneccesary messages to user.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text.count > 1 {
       // paste scenario
        if (urlExists(text.text))
        {
            // URL exists...
        }
    } else {
       //normal typing
    }
    return true
}
```